# Multiplying sequence of numbers until a selected number

Tags: python

how can I multiply numbers from 1,2,3,4,..... until the result is higher than 1000 using loops?
I have just begun learning Python and I am stuck with this exercise.

EDIT: Yes I did research on google, in my book, I tried what I thought could work, but couldn`t get it in the right direction, so I asked here. I check the stackoverflow if there is some similar question, but all I found were slightly different and couldn`t get me move on.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and include details of what you have tried. Consider including a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Please use Google first before posting questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes I tried more options and used google. Options I tried where not in the direction of my desirable result, so I didn`t find it necessary to post it. I will do next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# start with a result of 1
result = 1
# and a factor of 1
i = 1

# iterate until the variable result is bigger than 1000
while result <= 1000:
   # increase the factor
   i += 1
   # and multiply the result with this factor
   result *= i
   # print the current state
   print(i, result)
```

Comment: But as the other comments already mentioned, you should try the things yourself first. If you did so, you should write in your question, what you did and were your problems were with the implementation. Because if it is an exercise and you just ask for the answer, you don't learn much.

Comment: I was trying around 2 hours to sort it. I had many codes which didn`t lead to the result so I didn`t think it was necessary to write them all down.

Comment: Well, but it doesn't hurt to show the try that you think got closest to the result. That shows that you already tried something and serves as a starting point for the answers. Then the answer can explain what exactly goes wrong with your solution. So for the next time on Stack Overflow just give a code example along your question and your question will be received better.

Answer (score 0):

```
num1 = 1
num2 = 2
result = 0
while result<1000:
    result = num1 * num2
    print result
    num1 = num1 + 1
    num2 = num2 + 1
print result
```